# Is there any LTRIM function for MS ACCESS 2007?

Tags: sql, ms-access, trim

i am trying to ltrim 3 or 4 zeros from a column in Access 2007 but not getting any result where the data-type is text(from a csv data).

Comment: There is, and has always been, an LTrim in VBA. But, as RTrim and Trim, it removes _spaces_, not zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, MS Access in fact should support `LTRIM`.  Here is a workaround in case you need it:

```
SELECT
    IIF(string LIKE "0000*",
        MID(string, 5),
        IIF(string LIKE "000*", MID(string, 4), string)) output
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of quickly written `LTrim` & `RTrim` functions to operate with characters other than spaces:

```vb
Function LTrimChr(strStr As String, strChr As String) As String
    If strStr Like strChr & "*" Then
        LTrimChr = LTrimChr(Mid(strStr, 2), strChr)
    Else
        LTrimChr = strStr
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
Function RTrimChr(strStr As String, strChr As String) As String
    If strStr Like "*" & strChr Then
        RTrimChr = RTrimChr(Left(strStr, Len(strStr) - 1), strChr)
    Else
        RTrimChr = strStr
    End If
End Function
```

Expects the `strChr` to be a single character, e.g.:

```vb
?LTrimChr("000123456789000","0")
123456789000
```

```vb
?RTrimChr("000123456789000","0")
000123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of digits only, you can use *Val* to strip leading zeroes:

```
LTrimmedValue = CStr(Val(Value))
' "000123456789000" -> "123456789000"
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access supports `ltrim()`, but only for spaces.  So, assuming that your string has no spaces, you can use `replace()` and `ltrim()`:

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(col, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

If you do have spaces, there is often a character you don't have, so you can replace the spaces first:

```
select replace(replace(ltrim(replace(replace(col, ' ', '~'
                                            ), '0', ' '
                                    )
                            ), ' ', '0'
                      ), '~', ' '
              )
```